# swift 4. create marker by json url data

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to create marker on google map with json data from my url.
 GMS function for create marker must call on main thread.
When i create marker on main thread my data show count = 0.

```
var arrMarker = [Marker]()
var arrdata = [json_data]()

func getData(){

    let url = URL(string: "http://www.kalasinmots.go.th/json_service/get_data.php")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        do{
            if error == nil{
                self.arrdata = try JSONDecoder().decode([json_data].self, from: data!)
                //print("arrdata count = ",self.arrdata.count)
                for row in self.arrdata{

                if(row.data_latlng != ""){
                    print(row.data_id,":",row.data_name,":",row.data_latlng)

                    let latlng = row.data_latlng.components(separatedBy: ",")

                    let lat = latlng[0]
                    let lng = latlng[1]

                    let myLat = (lat as NSString).doubleValue
                    let myLng = (lng as NSString).doubleValue

                    self.arrMarker.append(Marker(name:row.data_name,lat:myLat,long:myLng))


                    for row in self.arrMarker{

                        self.marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: row.lat, longitude: row.long)
                        self.marker.title = row.name
                        self.marker.map = self.mapView

                        // Add the map to the view, hide it until we&#39;ve got a location update.
                        self.view.addSubview(self.mapView)
                                }

                }

                }
            }

        }catch{
            print("Error in get json data")
        }

        }.resume()

    print("addmarker show count = ",arrMarker.count)

}
```

Comment: Put the `print` line – and everything else you want to do after receiving the JSON data –  in the **asynchronous** closure after the `for row in self.arrMarker` loop.

Comment: Yes, the callback is asynchronous so your print statement is performed before the data has been downloaded

Comment: The whole closure , `{ (data, response, error) in ...` is. The closure gets called once the response from the server has been received

Comment: where is i can create marker exam please

Comment: Please reread my first comment.

Comment: ok but error create marker must call on main thread

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are after but you should do your UI updates on the main thread using `DispatchQueue.main.async` in the closure.